# Extracting the keywords from PDF metadata in Python

Tags: python, nlp, pypdf

I have a PDF file from which I want to obtain some information from its metada. To do so, I follow the follwoing procedure:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader    
mypath = "your_pdf_file.pdf"
pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(open(mypath, 'rb'))
pdf_info = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()
```

For the document at hand the output is:

```
Out[230]: 
{'/CrossmarkDomainExclusive': 'true',
 '/CreationDate': "D:20181029074117+05'30'",
 '/CrossMarkDomains#5B2#5D': 'elsevier.com',
 '/Author': 'Nicola Gennaioli',
 '/Creator': 'Elsevier',
 '/ElsevierWebPDFSpecifications': '6.5',
 '/Subject': 'Journal of Monetary Economics, 98 (2018) 98-113. doi:10.1016/j.jmoneco.2018.04.011',
 '/CrossmarkMajorVersionDate': '2010-04-23',
 '/CrossMarkDomains#5B1#5D': 'sciencedirect.com',
 '/robots': 'noindex',
 '/ModDate': "D:20181029074135+05'30'",
 '/AuthoritativeDomain#5B1#5D': 'sciencedirect.com',
 '/Keywords': 'Sovereign Risk; Sovereign Default; Government Bonds',
 '/doi': '10.1016/j.jmoneco.2018.04.011',
 '/Title': 'Banks, government Bonds, and Default: What do the data Say?',
 '/AuthoritativeDomain#5B2#5D': 'elsevier.com',
 '/Producer': 'Acrobat Distiller 10.1.10 (Windows)'}
```

I found out, however, that that the PyPDF2 library does not have an attribute to "access" the information for the `/Keywords` part. That is, this bit of output:

```
'/Keywords': 'Sovereign Risk; Sovereign Default; Government Bonds',
```

So, I want some help on how I could get this information of the metadata output [in this example: `Sovereign Risk; Sovereign Default; Government Bonds`].

To reproduce the output I am sharing a [link to the document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jB_Edgg7tggTRzpIm9mNGWydicYYGLFS/view?usp=sharing)

Doing for example

**Update:**

```
print(pdf_info.title)
Banks, government Bonds, and Default: What do the data Say?

print(pdf_info.subject)
Journal of Monetary Economics, 98 (2018) 98-113. doi:10.1016/j.jmoneco.2018.04.011
```

But when I am trying to do something similar for the `/Keywords` part I am getting the follwoing attribute error:

```
pdf_info.keywords
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-295-3852401ef983>", line 1, in <module>
    pdf_info.keywords

AttributeError: 'DocumentInformation' object has no attribute 'keywords'
```

Comment: Your link needs permission to access

Comment: What does "access" (quoted) mean? I can see the `/Keywords` entry right there.

Comment: if I do `pdf_toread.title` I can get the title, but when I do `pdf_toread.keywords` -- I get an error that this attribute does not exist. I looked at it and the authors of the PyPDF2 indeed have not programmed to get the keywords as you can get the information for title or,for example, subject.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by keywords? Is it that you want the headings or keywords from entire text? Give some examples of keywords please

Comment: check my updates. I thought was straightforward what I want. Basically, I am reading a pdf's metadata which as I show in my question it comes as a pdf document object and with the output seen in the question. There one can see what is the title, author, as well as a part called  `keywords`, which in the output I show is `'/Keywords': 'Sovereign Risk; Sovereign Default; Government Bonds' `. Although I can get the information for the title, by `pdf_info.title`, I cannot do the say for getting the information for keywords -- that  the output (metadata) above clearly shows it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `/Keywords` is actually present in the dictionary returned by `getDocumentInfo`, so you don't have to do anything special (except first testing if it is there or wrap this in a `try`, in case it is *not* present in another file):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader    
mypath = "../Downloads/banks_gov_bonds_default.pdf"
pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(open(mypath, 'rb'))
pdf_info = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()
if '/Keywords' in pdf_info:
    print (pdf_info['/Keywords'])
```

prints

```
Sovereign Risk; Sovereign Default; Government Bonds
```

which indeed are the keywords in the field inside your sample PDF.

The other option is to *add* `keywords` to the exposed PDF properties by editing `pdf.py` inside the PYPDF2 folder where your pip placed it. You can find the creation of the `title`, `creator`, `author` and some more properties in the class `DocumentInformation`, somewhere around line 2781 in my version. The creation of all of these properties follow a simple scheme and so adding one is no problem at all:

```
keywords = property(lambda self: self.getText("/Keywords"))
"""Read-only property accessing the document's **producer**.
If the document was converted to PDF from another format, this is
the name of the application (for example, OSX Quartz) that converted
it to PDF. Returns a unicode string (``TextStringObject``)
or ``None`` if the producer is not specified."""
keywords_raw = property(lambda self: self.get("/Keywords"))
"""The "raw" version of producer; can return a ``ByteStringObject``."""
```

(I added `keywords_raw` only because the other properties did so as well. I can't tell off-hand what these are for, though.)

After that your code actually works:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader    
mypath = "../Downloads/banks_gov_bonds_default.pdf"
pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(open(mypath, 'rb'))
pdf_info = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()
print (pdf_info.keywords)
```

Result, again:

```
Sovereign Risk; Sovereign Default; Government Bonds
```